# Struggling to make a complex query for NO-SQL

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have an object in MongoDB and trying to write a query that finds the document by `company_id` then goes through the `purchases` array and update `paid` to `true` in all record that matches with `user_id`, without overwriting the rest of the data.

```
{
    _id: 27834682,
    company_id: 27,
    purchases: [
        {
            paid: false,
            user_id: 19,
            items: [{...}, {...}],
            price: 1085
        },
        ...    
    ]
}
```

I was trying out

`Model.updateMany({company_id: company_id}, {"purchases.$[]": {$set: {paid: true}}})`

but it removed the other data in the object and could not even filtered by `user_id`.

What would be the correct approach for this query?

Comment: `{"$set": {"purchases.$[].paid": true}}` - have you tried this way?

Comment: It does update without overwriting, thanks. However, I still don't have idea how to filter by user_id as at this point, updating every object in the purchases array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When updating an array field, you can specify [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents) that determine which array elements to update.

Quick Fixes,

- define condition `user_id: 19` in `arrayFilters`, syntax `<user define key>.<identifier key>`,
- `element.user_id`, `element` is user define key, you can set any of the key name, `user_id` is
  identifier field inside array
- update operation start with `$set`
- set value for array element using `$[key]`, here `key` is user define key that we have defined in arrayFilters, it looks `purchases.$[element].paid`

```
Model.updateMany(
    { 
        company_id: company_id
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "purchases.$[element].paid": true
        }
    },
    { 
        arrayFilters: [ 
            { 
                "element.user_id": 19
            }
        ]
    }
)
```